# how to make auto input in textfield html

Tags: php, html

When I select one of the choice in the datalist, I want the textfield to be auto filled. I have this code but it does not work. Sorry my English is not good

```
<tr>
    <td width="15%"><div class="tabtxt">Pilih Pembayaran</div></td>
    <td width="2%"><div class="tabtxt">:</div></td>
    <td width="83%">
        <input list="bayar" name="bayar" style="width: 203px">
        <datalist id="bayar">
            <option value="Visual Basic Islam">
            <option value="Baitul Arqam">
            <option value="Shortcourse">
            <option value="Sertifikasi">
            <option value="Seminar SID">
            <option value="TOEFL & Bahasa Inggris">
        </datalist>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="15%"><div class="tabtxt">Kode Pembayaran</div></td>
    <td width="2%"><div class="tabtxt">:</div></td>
    <td width="83%">
        <input name="id_bayar" style="width: 200px" type="text" class="tfield" id="id_bayar">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#bayar").change(function(){
                var in = $("#bayar").val();
                $("id_bayar").val("hallo");
            });
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How do I solve this? Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 2):

Firstly add an id ,for example inbayar, to the input element:

```
<input id="inbayar" list="bayar" name="bayar" style="width: 203px">
```

They, you have to bind this html5 element's **event** like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#inbayar").bind('input', function () {
        $("#id_bayar").val(this.value);
        alert("Working!");
    });
});
```

Working solution here http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/gk3r8da9/

- Revision solution asked vol.1 http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/gk3r8da9/1/

Comment: how if in the textfield i want load data from database? can you tell me with example?

Comment: Sorry i am not such good at databases . You have to ask another question for that. Sorry i am a front end type :). hope i help until now!

Comment: ok thank alot, i'm really beginner in web programming. I have done what you write on my code before, but it still does not work, bellow complete code.

Comment: ok.. i have done what you write on your comment, but it still does not work, here my complete code. any wrong???
http://pastebin.com/uY8pGYQD

Comment: if you see the fiddle it works which means i was right at the question .You have to mark as completed . The mission is over but you have to make an otehr question for the database i think.Wish i could help more! sorry :)

Comment: may be you can look first which link i given at pastebin. on there no database topic

Comment: I hadn't see your pastebin link before.Sorry.The solution is here and updated the ansert too! http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/gk3r8da9/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
            <td width="15%"><div class="tabtxt">Pilih Pembayaran</div></td>
            <td width="2%"><div class="tabtxt">:</div></td>
            <td width="83%">

             <select  id="bayar">
            <option value="Visual Basic Islam">Visual Basic Islam</option>
            <option value="Baitul Arqam">Baitul Arqam</option>
            <option value="Shortcourse">Shortcourse</option>
            <option value="Sertifikasi">Sertifikasi</option>
            <option value="Seminar SID">Seminar SID</option>
            <option value="TOEFL & Bahasa Inggris">TOEFL & Bahasa Inggris</option>
          </select>
            </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="15%"><div class="tabtxt">Kode Pembayaran</div></td>
            <td width="2%"><div class="tabtxt">:</div></td>
            <td width="83%">
                <input name="alert();" style="width: 200px" type="text" class="tfield" id="id_bayar">

            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#bayar").on('change',function(){

            var a = $("#bayar").val();

            $("#id_bayar").val(a);
            });
    });

 </script>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, but if i want in the textfield load data from database, can you show me the code example. thanks for advanced